# Fatal Exception:AsyncTask (Android)

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

Im really dont know what is the error in my android code and hope someone can help me

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ProductCollection extends Activity {

    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private ViewGroup container;

    private static final ResourceBundle rb = ResourceBundle.getBundle("com.example.mobile_e_commerce.webserviceurl");

    private final String NAMESPACE = rb.getString("WSDLTargetNamespace");
  private  final String URL = rb.getString("SoapAddress");
   private final String SOAP_ACTION = rb.getString("SoapAction");
    private final String METHOD_NAME = rb.getString("OperationName");


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_product_collection);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
        }
    }
```

After this method execute the error will occur!

```
@Override
        protected void onResume(){
            super.onResume();
            try{
            (new dataLoader()).execute();
            }
            catch(Exception ee)
            {
                 TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Product1);
                 textView.setText(ee.toString());
            }
        }
```

The error should be come from doInBackground method

```
    class dataLoader extends AsyncTask<TextView,String,TextView>{



            ProductCollection pc = new ProductCollection();

         @Override
          protected TextView doInBackground(TextView... arg0) {
             TextView textView = new TextView(pc);

              textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Product1);     
                SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE,METHOD_NAME);



                        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(

                        SoapEnvelope.VER11);

                        envelope.dotNet = true;

                        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

                        HttpTransportSE httpTransport = new HttpTransportSE("http://192.168.10.12:57491/MEC_WebService.asmx");

                        try
                        {

                        httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

                        Object response = envelope.getResponse();

                        textView.setText("Hello World");


                        }

                        catch (Exception exception)
                        {
                                        textView.setText(exception.toString());

                        }
                        return textView;
         }

    //   @Override
        // protected void onPostExecute(TextView response) {

//          response = textView;
    //       super.onPostExecute(response);     
    //}
    }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.product_collection, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(
                    R.layout.fragment_product_collection, container, false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Show us a logcat stacktrace, sir.

Comment: You are changing the UI in doInBackground which you cannot do.. move `textView.setText("Hello World");` to onPostExecute()

Comment: after i change i gt java.lang.NullPointerException and i had moved the  TextView textView = new TextView(pc) outside of the method so that the textview.settext in onPostExecute can get initialized too....

Answer (score 0):

You can't touch a view from a background thread .. move your code that changes UI (sets text to edittext) to the `onPostExecute()` method

Comment: after i change i gt java.lang.NullPointerException and i had moved the  TextView textView = new TextView(pc) outside of the method so that the textview.settext in onPostExecute can get initialized too....

Comment: and actually my textview.settext want to set it to the response that i get from webservice~~~Hello world is just for testing///

Comment: Return the string or result from doInBackground() and use the passed parameter result in onPostExecute() ...

Comment: Sorry to ask again but how to pass parameter result that are from doInBackground///can u give me an example???

Comment: When you extend AsyncTask<Param, Param,Param> the last type is the type of the result which is returned from doInBackgrond() and automatically passed to onPostExeute() so what you return in doInBackground() you can receive in onPostExecute() and use it 
So you can return the desired string instead of textview